# Не находит std::begin, std::end

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели, шаблоны-с++, итераторы

Пишу простую шаблонную функцию `in_array`. По замыслу, она должна работать с любыми типами. Вот код:

```
template <typename T>
bool in_array(T needle, const T* haystack) {
    T *e = std::find(std::begin(haystack), std::end(haystack), needle);
    if (e != std::end(haystack))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Получаю ошибки:

> `std::begin`: не найдена соответствующая перегруженная функция

То же для `std::end`. В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: Используйте `std::array`, этим Вы решите множество проблем, как насущных, так и будущих.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Для указателей стандартные функции `std::begin` и `std::end` не определены.

Имея указатель, в общем случае, нельзя определить, указывает ли он на одиночный объект или на первый объект некоторой последовательности объектов. В виду этого нельзя определить функцию `std::end` для указателей, так как неизвестно число элементов, которые могут адресоваться указателем.

Вы могли бы свою функцию определить следующим образом

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
bool in_array(T needle, T ( &haystack )[N] ) {
    auto e = std::find(std::begin(haystack), std::end(haystack), needle);

    return e != std::end(haystack);
}
```

Либо вы можете эту функцию определить как

```
template <typename T>
bool in_array(T needle, T *haystack, size_t n ) {
    auto e = std::find( haystack, haystack + n, needle);

    return e != haystack + n;
}
```

включив в объявление функции еще один параметр, задающий число элементов в массиве.

Comment: Так ведь когда мы массив передаем, мы же передаем указатель на первый элемент, разве нет?

Comment: @Nik Смотрите мой дополненный ответ.

Comment: Всё равно не пойму. Когда я передаю массив int, например, в эту функцию, я же передаю тот же указатель и без числа элементов, но все работает...

Comment: @Nik Когда вы передаете массив по значению, то он преобразуется в указатель на свой первый элемент. Однако совершенно неизвестно, сколько элементов адресуется этим указателем. Поэтому если вы передаете массив по значению, вам также следует передавать в функцию число элементов в массиве.

Comment: Большое спасибо. А как в вашем первом варианте вычисляется N? При том же вызове функции `in_array(element, arr)` все работает, т.е. явно мы размер массива не передаем.

Comment: @Nik N выводится из передаваемого аргумента. Для каждого массива с различным числом элементов инстанциируется своя шаблонная функция. Я в своем ответе привел еще один вариант. Для этой шаблонной функции будет инстанциироваться только одна функция для конкретного типа T.

Comment: Стало интересно, как именно выводится N? Многие функции принимают параметр длины, а вы написали так элегантно-автоматизированно, чтобы все считалось само.

Comment: @Nik Когда массив передается по ссылке, а не преобразуется в указатель на свой первый элемент, то его тип известен компилятору.

Comment: А если компилятору известен тип, то ему известен и размер? Как компилятор определяет размер?

Comment: @Nik Тип массива - это T[N]. Компилятор знает тип любого объекта, который вы объявляете.

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался. А как мы можем обратится к этому N в коде(не в функции, а в теле main, там же где и был обьявлен массив), не прибегая к конструкции `sizeof/sizeof`?

Comment: @Nik Есть такой шаблонный класс как std::extent

Answer (score 2):

Для указателя эти функции не определены.